# Add item to listbox and select it

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a listbox (`SelectionMode` is set to `MultiExtended` as mentioned on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130788/selecting-multiple-listbox-items-through-code)) containing one single entry: `"..."`. When user double-clicks this a dialog appears to select a single file. When user selects one the dialog disappears and the file should be added to the list. This all works.

My problem is that **I want to select only that newly added entry within my listbox**. However with the following code both - the `"..."` and the actual file are selected:

```
private void lbx_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.lbx.SelectedItem == "..."
            && this.ofdReferences.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK
    {
        this.lbx.Items.Insert(this.lbx.SelectedIndex, this.ofdReferences.FileName);
        this.lbx.SetSelected(this.lbx.SelectedIndex - 1, true); // select newly added entry
    }
}
```

So I also added this line:

```
this.lbx.SetSelected(this.lbx.SelectedIndex, false);        // unselect ...
```

Now the `"..."`-entry is selected instead of the file.

I even tried to use `SelectedIndex = this.lbxProjectReferences.SelectedIndex - 1`. This also selects both entries within the list.

Comment: Why not use lbx.selectedIndex to set the selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SelectedIndex`-property is for single-select-lists. However we *can* use it on multi-lists also within a double-click-events also because a double-click will implicetly select one single item setting the `SelecteItem` correctly.

So I used this approach that deletes the list of selected entries and adds only that entry I´m interested in.

```
this.lbx.Items.Insert(this.lbx.SelectedIndex, this.ofdReferences.FileName);
var idx = this.lbx.SelectedIndex;
this.lbx.SelectedIndices.Clear();
this.lbx.SelectedIndices.Add(idx - 1);
```